# Foreach not updating HTML list elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, knockout.js

Using knockout 2.2.0
I'm trying to use the same dialog for add and edit.  I have the code mostly working, but when I replace the observable with the new edited one, it doesn't cause an update in the foreach (or at least it continues to display the old values)  It does update the actual model, as I can see in dev tools.  I even tried to force an update with .valueHasMutated(), but with no luck.

```
self.editReference = function () {
    self.isEdit(true);
    self.open();
    self.dialogReferences(this);
};

self.saveEditReference = function () {
    self.references.replace(this, self.dialogReferences);
    self.references.valueHasMutated();
    self.dialogReferences(newReferences());
    self.close();
};
```

And here is the some of the partial view with the references section of HTML code:

```
                    <ul class="sortable references-summary" data-bind="foreach: references">
                        <li class="ui-state-default"><b>Name: </b><!-- ko text:name --><!-- /ko--><br /><b>Company: </b><!-- ko text:company --><!-- /ko--><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeReference"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span></a><a href="#" data-bind="    click: $parent.editReference"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: There's too much code here, please isolate the problem and post only the relevant code. Creating a jsfiddle would also help.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit.  Was trying to give full context.

Comment: There, hopefully that's better!  @CrimsonChris

Comment: Your replace looks odd. Why are you replacing `this` in the references array? Making a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem will help you figure out what code is "necessary" to share here.

Comment: Primarily because     self.removeReference = function () { self.references.remove(this);} worked, so I figured when making the replace it would work the same way.  Working on the fiddle now.

Comment: Whether or not `this` will be correct there depends entirely on how it's being called.

Comment: I mean - it works.  It changes the viewModel (I can see it's changed in dev tools when I call ko.toJSON(viewModel.references).  So the issue is why isn't the foreach loop updating.  I'm still working on my plunkr, but running into a ton of dependency issues from jqui, knockout, jquery, etc.  But I'll keep at it.

Comment: Also worth noting - I tried this, and it didn't work either: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/936

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using the latest version of Knockout?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CrimsonChris for pointing out my bug. The updated code below works as expected.

The approach is to have a reference you are editing, in addition to the references in your array. When you start to edit, you copy the values from the array to your edit reference. When you save the edit, you copy them back. There is no need for `valueHasMutated` for this to work.

```js
function reference(name, company) {
  return {
    name: ko.observable(name),
    company: ko.observable(company)
  };
}

// Copy r1 into r2
reference.copy = function(r1, r2) {
  r2.name(r1.name());
  r2.company(r1.company());
}

var self = {
  editingReference: undefined,
  dialogReferences: reference('', ''),
  references: ko.observableArray([
    reference('One', 'First Company'),
    reference('Two', '2nd Company')
  ]),
  dialogIsOpen: ko.observable(false),
  open: function() {
    self.dialogIsOpen(true);
  },
  close: function() {
    self.dialogIsOpen(false);
  }
};

self.editReference = function(item) {
  self.editingReference = item;
  self.open();
  reference.copy(item, self.dialogReferences);
};

self.removeReference = function(item) {
  self.references.remove(item);
  self.close();
};

self.saveEditReference = function(item) {
  reference.copy(item, self.editingReference);
  self.close();
};

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable references-summary" data-bind="foreach: references">
  <li class="ui-state-default"> <b>Name: </b>

    <!-- ko text:name() -->
    <!-- /ko-->
    <br /> <b>Company: </b>

    <!-- ko text:company() -->
    <!-- /ko--> <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeReference"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span></a>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.editReference"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench"></span></a>

  </li>
</ul>
<div data-bind="if: dialogIsOpen">
  <div data-bind="with:dialogReferences">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input data-bind="value:name" />
    <br/>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input data-bind="value:company" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" data-bind="click: $parent.saveEditReference" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like editing one will copy the edited values to the other when you edit the second one.

Comment: Ugh, you're right. I was expecting a different side-effect from passing the array element to the edit box, but didn't get it, and didn't notice this one.